# Use ocaml attributes to raise a userdefined compiler warning

Tags: ocaml

Is there a way to attach an attribute to a function definition so that the compiler raise a user defined warning message, similarly to what [@@deprecated] does.

I would like to write something like

```
let dangerous_function[@@warn "use this function with caution, are sure ?"] = ...
```

and then, compiling the code

```
let _ = dangerous_function ...
```

would issue a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently possible but this might become a [new feature](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/1804) in OCaml 4.08

```
val foo: int -> int
    [@@ocaml.alert unsafe "Please use bar instead!"]
```